# Formatting numbers in a string without extracting them in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

so here's my problem: I want to format numbers found in a string. 
For example:

Input: '123.64 ABC'

Result: '124 ABC'

or

Input: '10.23% ABC'

Result: '10% ABC'

I tried Google but it seems that all questions are about extracting numbers, not formatting them inside the string. I guess that the input of Excel's formatting tools require number type so they don't work with cells that contain string. So is this possible? I'm thinking about splitting the string -> formatting the numbers -> then writing back to the string. Could anyone suggest a solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? [Edit] your question to show your code, and describe the specific problem  you have.

Comment: Your idea sounds good, why don't you try it?

Comment: You just have to `FIND` the space in the string to split it to separate the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` parts.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try to be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this

```
Sub teste()

 txt = "123.64 ABC"
 pos = InStr(1, txt, " ", vbTextCompare) 'search for space
 num = Left(txt, pos - 1) 'get number until space

'in my case i have to replace a "." by "," to be a number, but you have to test what happens in your case
 num = Replace(num, ".", ",", 1, 1) 

 numR = Round(num) ' round number
 Final = numR & " " & Mid(txt, pos + 1, 500) ' join round number and rest of string

End Sub
```

good luck

Comment: Thanks! Exactly as I thought. Now I just have to make an add-in from this.

Comment: No need to make an add-in, put the code in a normal module in your workbook and make these changes:  change procedure name to a function -  `Function teste(txt As String) As String`, remove the `txt = "123.64 ABC"` line and change `Final` to `teste` on the last row.  You can then use `=teste("123.64 ABC")`  or `=teste(A1)` directly in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use formula rather than VBA.

```
|   | A          | B  | C       |
|---|------------|----|---------|
| 1 | 123.64 ABC | #  | 124 ABC |
| 2 | 10.23% ABC | #% | 10% ABC |
```

The above table has your original values in cells `A1` & `A2`.
Cells `B1` and `B2` contain the [text format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) you'd like for the number on that row.

Cell `C1` contains the formula:

```
=TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)),B1) & MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1),LEN(A1))
```

**Edit:**  `VALUE` was needed so that 10.23% is converted to 0.1023 before being reformatted... when I tried first time *without* `VALUE` it returned an error, but now it doesn't... so may not need `VALUE` after all. :)